# Verilog array offset

Tags: verilog

```
module inst_mem(inst_out, pc_addr_out, clk, rstb);
output reg [31:0] inst_out;
input             clk, rstb;
input      [7:0]  pc_addr_out;
reg        [31:0] array[7:0];
//integer           n = 0;
initial begin 
    array[0] <= 32'b00001111000011110000111100001111;
    array[1] <= 32'b00011111000011110000111100001111; 
    array[2] <= 32'b00101111000011110000111100001111;
    array[3] <= 32'b00111111000011110000111100001111;
    array[4] <= 32'b01001111000011110000111100001111;
    array[5] <= 32'b01011111000011110000111100001111;
    array[6] <= 32'b01101111000011110000111100001111;
    array[7] <= 32'b01111111000011110000111100001111;
end 
always @(posedge clk or negedge rstb)
    if (!rstb)
        inst_out <= 32'd0;
    else begin
        inst_out <= array[pc_addr_out];
    //  inst_out <= array[n];
    end
endmodule
```

I write code for instruction memory and I found that first clock is delayed when I access to array with reg type like this

```
inst_out <= array[pc_addr_out];
```

But when I access to arry with integer type 'n'

```
inst_out <= array[n];
```

It works correctly. So, I want to access array with integer type but I have no idea about it.
I tried casting like C language, but it doesn't work. Is there any good way to change reg type to int type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the timing of your inputs and outputs, not the types. Your memory is a ROM, it should just be combinatorial logic with no clock or reset needed.

```
module inst_mem(
   output wire [31:0] inst_out,
   input  wire [7:0]  pc_addr_out
);

reg        [31:0] array[7:0];
initial begin 
    array[0] <= 32'b00001111000011110000111100001111;
    array[1] <= 32'b00011111000011110000111100001111; 
    array[2] <= 32'b00101111000011110000111100001111;
    array[3] <= 32'b00111111000011110000111100001111;
    array[4] <= 32'b01001111000011110000111100001111;
    array[5] <= 32'b01011111000011110000111100001111;
    array[6] <= 32'b01101111000011110000111100001111;
    array[7] <= 32'b01111111000011110000111100001111;
end 
assign inst_out <= array[pc_addr_out];
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: WOW, It works!! I spend a week because of this :(

Comment: I thought output must be reg type. I think I miss a lot because I'm self-taught.

Comment: but I can't understand clearly how does reg type occur timing issue